# How to override django-allauth templates in django 3.0.7 and django-allauth 0.43.0

Tags: python, django

I want to override django-allauth templates. I have done it before in `django==3.0.2`
and `django-allauth==0.41.0`. Now I am using `django==3.0.7` and `django-allauth==0.43.0`. Lasttime I configured my settings like that in the code sample. I have tried this it doesn't work. I have also tried other solutions like placing the templates inside another app's templates directory but still no luck.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And the templates folder structure is like this.

```
templates
   allauth
      account
      openid
      socialaccount
      tests
```

What am I doing wrong here?